# Escape sequence \a is not working

Tags: c, windows

I have the following piece of C language code, it is running good on my friend's laptop but it is not working in my laptop.

In this code afer this certain time period i wanted to make an alert beep, but it is not working, help please.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
 delay(500);
 if(i==9)
    printf("Time up \a");
}
```

Is there any solution in C to resolve this sort of dependency

Comment: What terminal are you on? Which terminal was your friend on?

Comment: Both of us are using windows 7 , with compaq laptops

Comment: Have you by chance [disabled the system beep](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-disable-system-beep-windows-7)?

Comment: No, i haven't disabled it

Comment: I've also faced this problem

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the output stays in the [stdio](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) buffer (each `FILE`, notably `stdout` is buffered; see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)).

I suggest adding a call to [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) like e.g.

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
  delay(500); 
  if(i==9) {
    printf("Time up \a");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

BTW, you could call `fflush(NULL);` to flush every `FILE` buffer.

I am not familiar with `delay`. I assume it is some kind of [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html).

As a rule of thumb, if you are not ending `printf` format strings with `\n` or if your `stdout` is not a terminal, you should occasionally call `fflush` (especially with `delay` or `sleep`). But don't call it too often neither.

<sup>PS. Consider installing Linux on your laptop[s]. And consider using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (perhaps later customizing it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)). It is so fun, and it is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) so you can study the internal implementations.</sup>